Conspiracy of Doors Adventure Origin
In 4th Edition's Dungeon Master Guide 2, in the back of the book it goes over details for Planescape's center piece City of Sigil, and some notes on how to incorporate it into 4e alternate cosmology. After that section there is a short adventure called A Conspiracy of Doors
I've been told this adventure is actually a re-write of an uncompleted adventure written for 2e's Planescape that was suppose to take place immediately after the Faction War. It's current 4e iteration has been re-written and re-worked to fit that edition, honestly it's neat but not the greatest adventure ever written. I am told there is some interview in one of the 4e Dragon Magazines, and possibly on some forum-board somewhere.
I am looking for any background, writeup, or heck even the specific author's name for the A Conspiracy of Doors adventure. Any background information would suffice for this question.

I understand this might end up a bit of a false-Negative if there is simply no information regarding this adventure's background. My searching has turned up nothing. I'll re-word the question if required.

Conspiracy of Doors is possibly by Chris Perkins
The author is Chris Perkins, according to "Adventure Lookup". You can see the article that is discussing the Sigil material in Dragon 380, p. 92. It makes mention of the inclusion of old material, but not for the adventure in particular:

Michele [Carter]: I wrote the two-page “Faces of Sigil” spread. That’s not the interesting thing. The interesting thing is when I wrote it—back in 1997, when the Planescape team was working on a project called City of Doors, meant to follow Faction War. As it happened, some of the material from City of Doors was integrated into Faction War, but not all of it. One of the “lost” pieces was a 30-page section I had been compiling that
listed all of the Sigil residents noted throughout the Planescape game line. When Managing Editor Kim Mohan and I were wrangling Dungeon Master’s Guide
2 into shape, I realized that with a little bit of nipand-tuck, we could free up two more pages for Sigil. And I just happened to have kept all the City of Doors files ... on floppy disc. Thankfully, I had a computer
that could still access the files, so with a little bit of translation work—and some small amount of updating—those two pages were ready to go.

